# set focus to button on tab

Tags: jquery, button, focus, highlighting, blur

Hi I am trying to set focus to a button when it is tabbed to. The problem I am having is that when i add in the background image for the button the focus color is not being shown around the image but if I remove the image the button works great. How can I put a border around the button when it has focus and reset it on blur?

```
<html>
 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('button:button').focus(function(){ 
    $(this).css({'background-color' : 'red'}); 
  }); 
  $('button:button').blur(function(){ 
    $(this).css({'background-color' : 'lightgreen'}); 
  }); 
});
</script>


</head>
<body> 
   <button type='button' id='btnSubmit' style="background-image:     
    urlbuttonBackground.gif);"       >button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery 1.3? That's pretty ancient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these styles defined in a css class and then apply the class on `focus` and remove it on `blur`. Try this.

Remove the inline styling from `button`

```
<button type='button' id='btnSubmit'>button</button>
```

Css (define the styles as per your need)

```
button{
    background: lightgreen;
}
.focusBg{
    background: ulr('urlbuttonBackground.gif');
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     //Since the button has an id, you can use id selector
     $('#btnSubmit').focus(function(){ 
          $(this).addClass('focusBg');
     }).blur(function(){ 
          $(this).removeClass('focusBg');
     }); 
});
```